# Building GDCM with VTK

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cmake, vtk, gdcm

I tried to do (hxr99.blogspot.nl/2013/03/qt-vtk-displaying-dicom-series-using.html) but Qt throws error : `error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'vtkgdcm.lib'`
I did everything in [here](https://forge.imag.fr/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/camitk/index.php/GDCM) for windows. I checked GDCM_USE_VTK and GDCM_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS and then generated but when Im opening the project in VS 2008 there is no project vtkgdcm.
how can i do :

```
The project vtkgdcm uses VTK, thus at link stage, it links vtkgdcm-debug.dll against some vtk***.dll files. Unfortunately, it doesn't take the input debug version of that VTK dlls. You will have then to provide the good version of the VTK input dll files.
```

when there is no vtkgdcm project?

this is after opening solution in vs:
[#image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QMMR.png)

am I mising something here? I already built VTK